# Sets module deprecated warning

Tags: python

When I run my python script I get the following warning

```
DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Stop using the `sets` module, or switch to an older version of python where it's not deprecated.

According to [pep-004](https://peps.python.org/pep-0004/), `sets` is deprecated as of v2.6, replaced by the built-in [`set` and `frozenset` types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: +1: fix the warning by fixing the problem that causes the warning.  It seems so simple.

Comment: It only seems simple if you know that there is a built in replacing it.  Why doesn't the warning say so!?

Answer (score 28):

History:

Before Python 2.3: no set functionality
Python 2.3: `sets` module arrived
Python 2.4: `set` and `frozenset` built-ins introduced
Python 2.6: `sets` module deprecated

You should change your code to use `set` instead of `sets.Set`.

If you still wish to be able to support using Python 2.3, you can do this at the start of your script:

```
try:
   set
except NameError:
   from sets import Set as set
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to fix it James definitely has the right answer, but in case you want to just turn off deprecation warnings, you can run python like so:

```
$ python -Wignore::DeprecationWarning 
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Sep 20 2009, 20:47:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sets
>>>
```

(From: https://puzzling.org/uncategorized/2009/05/python26-deprecation-warning/)

You can also ignore it programmatically:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in `set` instead of importing and using `sets` module.

From [documentation](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html):

> The sets module has been deprecated;
>   it’s better to use the built-in set
>   and frozenset types.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import the `sets` module to use them, they're in the builtin namespace.